# Upgraded remove server from Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS to 22.0.4 LTS - now server keeps rebooting (Lassie)

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, reboot, syslog

I recently upgraded my remote Linode, an Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS server, to Ubuntu 22.0.4 LTS.

Ever since then, Lassie keeps rebooting my server, roughly, every 15 minutes. I have looked into both `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log - here are the contents:

[[Note]]: I have only included parts of the log file that seemed significant (to avoid having to post entire log file contents here).

#### syslog

```
Dec  7 00:00:01 ceberus CRON[3612]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/certbot renew --quiet)
Dec  7 00:00:01 ceberus CRON[3613]: (erpnext) CMD (cd /opt/bench/erpnext && /usr/local/bin/bench --verbose --site all backup >> /opt/bench/erpnext/logs/backup.log 2>&1 # bench auto backups set for every 6 hours) 
Dec  7 00:00:01 ceberus CRON[3614]: (erpnext) CMD (cd /home/erpnext/frappe-bench && /usr/local/bin/bench --verbose --site all backup >> /home/erpnext/frappe-bench/logs/backup.log 2>&1 # bench auto backups set for every 6 hours)
Dec  7 00:00:01 ceberus CRON[3615]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew)
Dec  7 00:00:01 ceberus systemd[1]: Starting Daily dpkg database backup service...
Dec  7 00:00:01 ceberus systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
Dec  7 00:00:01 ceberus CRON[3621]: (erpnext) CMD (cd /opt/bench/erpnext && /opt/bench/env/bin/bench --verbose --site all backup >> /opt/bench/erpnext/logs/backup.log 2>&1 # bench auto backups set for every 6 hours)
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus kernel: [  453.683560] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=f2:3c:91:4f:81:af:84:78:ac:1c:ec:41:86:dd SRC=2a06:4880:4000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0061 DST=2600:3c00:0000:0000:f03c:91ff:fe4f:81af LEN=64 TC=40 HOPLIMIT=243 FLOWLBL=27227 PROTO=TCP SPT=43519 DPT=33012 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus systemd[1]: dpkg-db-backup.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus systemd[1]: Finished Daily dpkg database backup service.
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/pickup[2505]: 1740DDC485: uid=1002 from=<erpnext>
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/cleanup[3645]: 1740DDC485: message-id=<20221207000002.1740DDC485@ceberus.members.linode.com>
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/qmgr[2506]: 1740DDC485: from=<erpnext@ceberus.members.linode.com>, size=761, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/pickup[2505]: 23F16DC3BA: uid=1002 from=<erpnext>
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/qmgr[2506]: 23F16DC3BA: from=<erpnext@ceberus.members.linode.com>, size=785, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/pickup[2505]: 29FD6DC3BC: uid=1002 from=<erpnext>
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/cleanup[3645]: 29FD6DC3BC: message-id=<20221207000002.29FD6DC3BC@ceberus.members.linode.com>
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/qmgr[2506]: 29FD6DC3BC: from=<erpnext@ceberus.members.linode.com>, size=765, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus systemd[1]: Started snap.certbot.certbot.2d0b6daa-1d1a-4726-ae2a-083c23951938.scope.
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/local[3649]: 1740DDC485: to=<erpnext@ceberus.members.linode.com>, orig_to=<erpnext>, relay=local, delay=0.39, delays=0.26/0.12/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/qmgr[2506]: 1740DDC485: removed
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/local[3649]: 23F16DC3BA: to=<erpnext@ceberus.members.linode.com>, orig_to=<erpnext>, relay=local, delay=0.4, delays=0.27/0.12/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/qmgr[2506]: 23F16DC3BA: removed
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/local[3649]: 29FD6DC3BC: to=<erpnext@ceberus.members.linode.com>, orig_to=<erpnext>, relay=local, delay=0.44, delays=0.29/0.12/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus postfix/qmgr[2506]: 29FD6DC3BC: removed
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus systemd[1]: Stopping Make remote CUPS printers available locally...
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus systemd[1]: cups-browsed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus systemd[1]: Stopped Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus systemd[1]: Stopping CUPS Scheduler...
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus systemd[1]: docker-957e78ab60b5025c0233702e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus systemd[1]: docker-957e78ab60b5025c0233702e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9.scope: Consumed 9.037s CPU time.
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus dockerd[1235]: time="2022-12-07T00:00:02.692286512Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=957e78ab60b5025c0233702e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus containerd[1055]: time="2022-12-07T00:00:02.696700524Z" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=957e78ab60b5025c0233702e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9
02e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus containerd[1055]: time="2022-12-07T00:00:02.696700524Z" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=957e78ab60b5025c0233702e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus containerd[1055]: time="2022-12-07T00:00:02.711375120Z" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=957e78ab60b5025c0233702e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9 namespace=moby
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus containerd[1055]: time="2022-12-07T00:00:02.712001642Z" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus containerd[1055]: time="2022-12-07T00:00:02.757962688Z" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2022-12-07T00:00:02Z\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=3675 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"
Dec  7 00:00:02 ceberus systemd[1]: mnt-startup_hub_volume-var-lib-docker-overlay2-597f724566a93c983ea6857579b541d3ca102c4c0191bd030404e42d636b9d5a-merged.mount: Deactivated successfully.


Dec  7 00:12:34 ceberus systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-957e78ab60b5025c0233702e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9-runc.PGShN2.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Dec  7 00:12:42 ceberus systemd[1]: docker-957e78ab60b5025c0233702e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Dec  7 00:12:42 ceberus systemd[1]: docker-957e78ab60b5025c0233702e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9.scope: Consumed 8.193s CPU time.
Dec  7 00:12:42 ceberus dockerd[1235]: time="2022-12-07T00:12:42.936044176Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=957e78ab60b5025c0233702e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Dec  7 00:12:42 ceberus containerd[1055]: time="2022-12-07T00:12:42.937086374Z" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=957e78ab60b5025c0233702e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9
Dec  7 00:12:42 ceberus containerd[1055]: time="2022-12-07T00:12:42.937551034Z" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=957e78ab60b5025c0233702e24669d20133da47cbefbef1ac655a8fc46fd95d9 namespace=moby
Dec  7 00:12:42 ceberus containerd[1055]: time="2022-12-07T00:12:42.937730763Z" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
Dec  7 00:12:42 ceberus containerd[1055]: time="2022-12-07T00:12:42.948888416Z" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2022-12-07T00:12:42Z\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=5266 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"


Dec  7 00:12:42 ceberus containerd[1055]: time="2022-12-07T00:12:42.948888416Z" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2022-12-07T00:12:42Z\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=5266 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"
Dec  7 00:12:43 ceberus systemd[1]: mnt-startup_hub_volume-var-lib-docker-overlay2-597f724566a93c983ea6857579b541d3ca102c4c0191bd030404e42d636b9d5a-merged.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus NetworkManager[579]: <info>  [1670371970.4317] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus gnome-shell[1226]: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus ModemManager[713]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...



Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus ModemManager[713]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Dec  7 00:12:50 ceberus systemd-sleep[5283]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd-modules-load[371]: Failed to find module 'lp'
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd-modules-load[371]: Failed to find module 'ppdev'



Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd-resolved[439]: Using system hostname 'CEBERUS'.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd-udevd[446]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd-udevd[426]: sdb: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdb' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd-udevd[445]: sda: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sda' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Found device /dev/ttyS0.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd-udevd[429]: sdc: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdc' failed with exit code 1.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Found device Virtio network device.



Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Reached target System Initialization.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch) being skipped.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.path.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: whoopsie.path: Refusing to start, unit whoopsie.service to trigger not loaded.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Failed to start Start whoopsie on modification of the /var/crash directory.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Started Trigger anacron every hour.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (timer based) being skipped.
```

#### kern.log

```
Dec  7 00:11:07 ceberus kernel: [ 1118.799235] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=REDACTED SRC=92.63.196.38 DST=45.33.121.232 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=241 ID=41428 PROTO=TCP SPT=53496 DPT=4749 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Dec  7 00:11:28 ceberus kernel: [ 1140.500279] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=REDACTED SRC=176.111.174.81 DST=45.33.121.232 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=237 ID=48644 PROTO=TCP SPT=46148 DPT=33388 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Dec  7 00:12:06 ceberus kernel: [ 1177.695725] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=REDACTED SRC=222.186.170.196 DST=45.33.121.232 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=238 ID=25486 PROTO=TCP SPT=33446 DPT=4300 WINDOW=63540 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Dec  7 00:12:24 ceberus kernel: [ 1196.427023] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=REDACTED SRC=79.124.62.130 DST=45.33.121.232 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x40 TTL=234 ID=23062 PROTO=TCP SPT=47912 DPT=4000 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Dec  7 00:12:25 ceberus kernel: [ 1197.072018] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=REDACTED SRC=212.70.149.46 DST=45.33.121.232 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x40 TTL=234 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=59239 DPT=8443 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 6.0.2-x86_64-linode157 (maker@build.linode.com) (gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.31.1) #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct 17 13:01:41 EDT 2022
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: root=/dev/sda console=tty1 console=ttyS0 ro  devtmpfs.mount=1
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] signal: max sigframe size: 1776
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009fbff] usable
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009fc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000007ffd6fff] usable



Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Reached target System Initialization.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (file watch) being skipped.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.path.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: whoopsie.path: Refusing to start, unit whoopsie.service to trigger not loaded.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Failed to start Start whoopsie on modification of the /var/crash directory.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Started Trigger anacron every hour.
Dec  7 00:13:31 ceberus systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled (timer based) being skipped.
...
```

I don't know enough about the contents of `syslog` and `kern.log` to be able to discern if there is any information in here, that explains why the server is being restarted - and equally (if not more) importantly, how to FIX this issue.

Comment: How did you go from 16.04.4 to 22.04? A number of the necessary repositories would have been shut down for over a year 

Comment: Typo. I meant 18.0.4 LTS. I'll ammend my question.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Please edit your question to fix the typo, relevant information should be correct in your question. There is no supported path to upgrade directly from 18.04 to 22.04, so the question remains how you did it.

Comment: You can upgrade from one release to the next (18.04 to 18.10) OR one LTS release to the next (ie. 18.04 to 20.04).  You're describing a *unsupported* upgrade that isn't QA tested & thus *breakage* could have been expected.  Why not use *supported* upgrade paths?   You may need to examine what you missed with 20.04 system changes to see what your system is missing (*so you can manually make them - that's on a package basis, not system level*)

Comment: @guiverc that's surprising, because I did `sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y` and afterwards, the system informed me that a new release 22.04 LTS was available and that if I wanted to upgrade, I should run `do-release-upgrade` - and I simply followed the on screen commands :/

Comment: A *release-upgrade* from 18.04 is available to 20.04, but not direct to 22.04.  A *release-upgrade* from 20.04 is likewise available to 22.04, as in each case the *release-upgrade* is to the **next** LTS release and not skipping any.   If you were on 18.04 & jumped to 22.04, then your sources & system were likely polluted & you weren't actually on 18.04 but a *frakensystem* where problems would have been expected.

Comment: Hmmm. This is likely what would have happened.  It is a bit disappointing that I ended up in this "bleak house" state - even as a Linux user for over a decade. I will try to roll back to a previous version and see if that resolves the issue.